# How to install Python library (Openpyxl) in QGIS 2.18.16?

Tags: qgis, python

I need to use GniPlannerFTTH, but this plugin does not work without the Openpyxl python library installed. **How can I install Openpyxl in QGIS?**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way using QGIS is:

- Open Python QGIS Console And:

  ```
  import pip
  pip.main(['install', 'Openpyxl'])
  ```

or in a cmd:

> pip install openpyxl

Comment: Ip?are you sure that write corret pip name?

Comment: Make sure your target is correct if you have more than one Python version installed. 
  _pip install --target="C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages" openpyxl_

Comment: WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\ProgrammiAC\QGIS3.16\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

What does it mean the last sentence. Can someone translate in easier words?