# Using Hot Spot Analysis Plugin on QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, installation

I need a help on trying to use the Hot Spot Analysis Plugin on QGIS Noosa. I am not able to install the module "moran".

Comment: intall using something like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/269766/49538

Comment: What kind of error do you encounter when you try to use the plugin?

Comment: Hi Kadir, this is the error I found: This is the error I found :Couldn't load plugin 'HotspotAnalysis' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moran'.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to install Pysal, as mentioned in the plugin description: "The plugin requires Pysal (see repository for installation instruction)" ?

Answer (score 4):

The module `moran` is a part of `pysal` package. So you can't install it using pip or something.

Developers of `pysal` changed the folder structure of the package. This is probably why you can't use the plugin or are getting errors.  Hotspot Analysis plugin needs an update, but you follow such a temporary solution I explain below.

If you look at `hotspot_analysis.py` file ([QGIS 3 Plugins folder location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/274311/29431)), you will see the lines (line numbers may be different than yours. I skipped the indentation).

```py
Line 39 from pysal.esda.getisord import *
Line 40 from pysal.esda.moran import *
Line 41 from pysal.weights.Distance import DistanceBand
.
Line 472 thresh = pysal.min_threshold_dist_from_shapefile(path)
.
Line 600 moran = pysal.Moran(y, w)
.
Line 608 w = pysal.knnW_from_shapefile(layerName.split("|")[0], k=weightValue, p=1)
.
Line 613 w = pysal.queen_from_shapefile(layerName.split("|")[0])
```

Change those lines into the lines below, respectively.

```py
from pysal.explore.esda.getisord import *
from pysal.explore.esda.moran import *
from pysal.lib.weights import DistanceBand, Queen, KNN, user
.
thresh = user.min_threshold_dist_from_shapefile(path)
.
moran = Moran(y, w)
.
w = KNN.from_shapefile(layerName.split("|")[0], k=weightValue, p=1)
.
w = Queen.from_shapefile(layerName.split("|")[0])
```

Save the changes and re-activate the plugin or re-open QGIS.

Comment: Thanks Kadir. You are simply Amazing. Your recommendations worked perfectly.

Comment: But it solves temporarily. When I select a line layer, I encounter an error, as an example.

Comment: I am afraid I also encountered an error as well while performing the analysis. This is the error I got "TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype(' " Any idea how to work around this.

Comment: If I use a 'string' field, I get the same error, too. I have no idea.

Comment: This explains why you can only use a numeric field while using ArcGIS. I will try to use a numeric field. Thanks